# Sealing Ceiling holes

Tags: ceiling, seal

I am renting a very small townhouse that has termite issues.  At certain times of the year (termite season)  I get dropping coming into my bathroom, laundry room and now kitchen.

I have told the person I rent from and she has been fighting with the association to get the place tented...but in the mean time I would like to do something about this situation that I am living with and would like to know.......

Is there something I can painter like a sealer to close up the wholes??

ANY recommendations would be greatly appreiciated!

Answer (score 1):

For small nail holes, use spackle. This is the simplest, cheapest way to fill small holes that aren't subject to significant movement.

For cracks/seams, such as at corners or around window trim, use caulk (probably a paintable latex or latex+silicone caulk, as they're easy to work with).

For deeper holes/cavities, such as around a pipe that is going through your floor, use expanding spray foam. This product will expand around whatever stuff is there, providing a good seal to block insects. But beware that the expansion can come with a lot of force, so don't overfill; if you're working in tight places, the expansion can cause damage. Around windows and doors especially use a minimum-expansion foam.

After patching the hole, make sure to seal the repair with primer before you paint it.